# Removing first member of a string set in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, set

Suppose I have a string set {'15, 1, 5, 4'} stored in MySQL variable. Is there any way to remove only '15' out of the set without knowing the exact position of the index where the first comma appears?

Meaning if there was another set with a different length member in the first position it should work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Mid('15, 1, 5, 4',locate(',','15, 1, 5, 4')+1)
```

Comment: I did solve it another way, with a while loop and STRCMP. This is a much better answer though.